# Change a string color from a json

Tags: php, css, json

I have a json file that looks like this

```
[{
"name":"P90 | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
"url":"http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/market\/listings\/730\/P90%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Field-Tested%29\"id=\"resultlink_0",
"price":"<span style=\"color:white\">8.35 USD<\/span>\r\n","image":"http:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz5rbbOKMyJYYl2STKFNVfw3-x7TBCI24dJuGoOy8-0EKgrv5YaVMbgkOIpJTcbSU_OFYwuo7UIxg_JafJCMqXvqjn_3ejBdkE3axU4\/62fx62f",
"quantity":"71",
"game":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive"
}]
```

...

When i want to diplay it i use this code

```
...

<tr>
<td><?php echo $data->name; ?></td>
<td><img src="<?php echo $data->image; ?>" /></td>
<td><?php echo $data->game; ?></td>
<td style="background:black"><?php echo $data->price; ?></td>
<td><?php echo (int)str_replace(',','',$data->quantity); ?></td>
<td><a target="blank" href="<?php echo $data->url; ?>">Buy</a></td>
</tr>

...
```

Now the problem is that the color of price is always white, i tryed to change the style of table but color is not changeing.

Any ideas?

Comment: `, i tryed to change` How did you try?

Comment: Are you able to see which <td> or <tr> or<table> it's in? Or how does the rendered html display?

Comment: I tryed this : <td style="color:black"><?php echo $data->price; ?></td> .

Comment: first of all you should optimize your json so its more atomic. you are sending html + data via a json. thats ugly.

Comment: As above, ideally you should just fix the json. Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you are echoing contains colors in it for some reason. Just remove them first using [php strip_tags() function.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
<td style="background:black"><?php echo (strip_tags($data->price)); ?></td>
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is a very good solution to a problem that originates from how the data was stored. When storing data only the data and no markup should be stored.

Comment: Yes - ideally the json should not have the `colors` in the first place - that would be the *real* solution :)

Comment: Also , raw json file looked like this http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=0&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=quantity&sort_dir=asc&appid=730 . I alreday optimize it a lot but looks like i had some mistakes . Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by css property color as below:

```
<td style="background:black;color:red;"><?php echo $data->price; ?></td>
```

Comment: I already tryed this but its not working.

Comment: You price value already contains color propery so that this is not working.

Comment: yeah i know , but how to solve this ?

Comment: Can you change in your json file?

Comment: try <?php echo strip_tags($data->price); ?>

Comment: If it is not works then try <td style="background:black;color:red !important;"><?php echo $data->price; ?></td>